Nextjs Script Doesn't Work With Conditionals
// _document.js, doesn't work
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const nonce = "1234-abcd-wxyz";
// ...
<Html lang="en">
  <Head nonce={nonce}>
  {isProduction && <Script
      async
      defer
      strategy="afterInteractive"
      src={`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY || ""}`}
    />}
  </Head>
</Html>


// _document.js, working
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const nonce = "1234-abcd-wxyz";
// ...
<Html lang="en">
  <Head nonce={nonce}>
  <Script
      async
      defer
      strategy="afterInteractive"
      src={isProduction ? `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY || ""}` : ""}
    />
  </Head>
</Html>

I'm using Next.js 13.5. I wanted to use Google Recaptcha script only if it is Production Mode. So I tried as the given code above.
In Production Mode, conditional on the script component NOT load the script but conditional on the src attribute DOES. What is the difference and what causes it, the framework?
